# docker maven repository not copied to /root/.m2

Tags: java, docker, maven

according to the [docker maven image documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven?tab=description),

> The $MAVEN_CONFIG dir (default to /root/.m2) could be configured as a
> volume so anything copied there in a Dockerfile at build time is lost.
> For that reason the dir /usr/share/maven/ref/ exists, and anything in
> that directory will be copied on container startup to $MAVEN_CONFIG.

the contents of `/usr/share/maven/ref/` should be copied to `/root/.m2` when the container is started. I am using a Dockerfile like below

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-adoptopenjdk-8
COPY pom.xml /tmp/pom.xml
RUN mvn -B -f /tmp/pom.xml -s /usr/share/maven/ref/settings-docker.xml install
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml /app/
COPY ./src /app/src
ENTRYPOINT ["mvn","test"]
```

The above dockerfile builds an image where the dependencies are stored in `/usr/share/maven/ref/repository`. However, when the container is started, the contents are not copied to `/root/.m2` and the dependencies are completely re-downloaded.

am i missing something here? are there any special steps that needs to be run to copy the repository contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the repository to be copied, the parent image's entrypoint should be called.

The Dockerfile has the following :

> ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh"]
>
> CMD ["mvn", "test"]

`ENTRYPOINT` is same as the [docker maven image's](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven) entrypoint. It has the logic to copy the repository to $MAVEN_CONFIG (default is `/root/.m2`)